# A contradiction I found with integrals and limits of an exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

"a" is a constant.
$$\lim_{a\to 0^+} \int e^{ax} \, dx = \lim_{a\to 0^+} \frac{e^{ax}}{a}=\frac{e^{0^+\times x}}{0^+}=\frac{1}{0^+}=\infty$$

but doing it in a different order:

$$\lim_{a\to 0^+} \int e^{ax} \, dx =\int e^{0^+\times x} \, dx=\int e^{0} \, dx=\int 1 \, dx=x$$

so which one is it? why did I get this contradiction? Thanks.

Comment: You cannot carelessly interchange the order of operations involving limits. Google “interchange of limiting operations”.

Comment: The first integral needs a "+C" - and this constant depends on a, so you can't take the limit in the unbounded integral like this. Try taking the bounded integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate your function from $0$ to $x$ like this:

$$\lim_{a\to 0^+}\int_0^x e^{at} \, dt = \lim_{a\to 0^+} \bigg(\frac{1}{a} e^{ax} - \frac{1}{a}\bigg).$$

You can see how this plays out from here. I prefer definite integrals with a variable upper bound because of issues like this amongst others. I have personally become, pardon the word play, very anti antiderivative over time. (Does that mean I'm derivative?)

Comment: You can check what happens if you adjust the limit on $a$ and the lower limit. Or what happens if you switch it to be a variable lower limit instead of upper limit.

Comment: I see. What other things made you dislike indefinite integrals? This kind of breaks my heart, I always liked the indefinite one over the definite one.

Comment: Indefinite integrals hide some behavior. Consider $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. The indefinite integral would give you $\log(|x|) + C$. However you technically have two constants of integration as a result of the discontinuity at $0$: one for positive $x$ and one for negative $x$. This is a bit easier to see if you think about indefinite integrals. You can't integrate across $0$, so you have to start at, say, $1$ or $-1$ when integrating $\frac{1}{x}$, like $\int_1^x \frac{1}{x}\,dx$ for positive $x$ or $\int_{-1}^x \frac{1}{x}\,dx$ for negative $x$.

Comment: Furthermore, the fundamental theorem of calculus is cast in the language of definite integrals primarily. Also indefinite integrals are defined implicitly (it's the function such that its derivative is your original function) whereas definite integrals are given explicitly via the Riemann sum definition. And lastly, indefinite integrals don't generalize well outside of the reals, but definite do (if you tweak the idea slightly).

Answer (score 0):

It should be
$$
\int e^{ax}dx = \frac{e^{ax}}{a}+C.
$$
$C$ is an arbitrary constant and can always be chosen as $-\frac{1}{a}+C'$. So, you can see that both limits coincide.

Comment: But what if we choose it to be something else?

Comment: You get an inconsistency as the OP's question is there to show. In the original question, the integration constants are systematically omitted and this is not correct.

Comment: This doesn't preclude $C'$ from depending on $a$.

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to MSE!

You got the "contradiction" because in general, the limit and integration operations are not interchangeable.